# How to edit user-config.jam for Boost and gcc in Windows 10?

Tags: boost-python, user-config

I'm trying to install Boost Python. The OS is Windows 10. The compiler is gcc. How do you edit the user-config.jam file?

Please give any suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using gcc on Windows 7. My user-config.jam simply looks like this:

```
using gcc ;
using python : 3.6 : "C:/Program Files/Python36" : "C:/Program Files/Python36/include" : "C:/Program Files/Python36/libs" ;
```

The rest are comment lines.